# select 2 records from DB that do not exist in 2 fields from another DB

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pull 2 records (limit 2) from the DB 'items' that dont exist together in 'item_matches' in either fields 'fA' or 'fB'.

```
    item_matches
    +------+------+
    | fA   |  fB  |
    +------+------+
    | abc  |  roc |
    | def  |  pod |
    | ghi  |  his |
    | 4    |  6   |
    | 5    |      |
    +------+------+


    +------+
    | items|
    +------+
    | abc   |
    | def   |
    | ghi   |
    | roc   |
    | pop   |
    | blr   |
    | doc   |
    +------+
```

### so this is result from a query:

abc and roc not selected

roc and abc not selected

ghi and roc selected

### another query

def and pod not selected

ghi and his not selected

doc and pod selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach here is to take a cross join of the `items` table to generate all pairs, then left join that against the `item_matches` table to check for pairs which are not exact matches.  The logic here is that if either of the join columns `fA` or `fB` be null, then it implies that an exact match for that pair could not be found.

```
SELECT i.item1, i.item2
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.BAND AS item1, t2.BAND AS item2
    FROM items t1
    INNER JOIN items t2
        ON t1.BAND <> t2.BAND
    WHERE t1.active = 1 AND t2.active = 1
) i
LEFT JOIN item_matches im
    ON i.item1 = im.fA AND
       i.item2 = im.fB
WHERE
    im.fA IS NULL OR im.fB IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2;
```

I chose to use a random ordering in the above query, but you might want to change that.  In any case, it generally does not make much sense to use `LIMIT` on a result set without providing an ordering (because you haven't told the database *which* 2 records you want to retain).

### Demo

Comment: +10. I read the spec as calling for checking for matches `(fB,fA)` as well as `(fA,fB)`  (maybe I'm overthinking it, and the query in this answer will work)

Comment: @spencer7593 I saw you joined twice, and wasn't sure why.  Let's see what the OP has to say.

Comment: I did the two antijoins to avoid a performance killing OR  `( a=fA AND b=fB ) OR ( a=fB AND b=fA )`

Comment: this worked for me but running the query on the item_matches db with 2111 records took 1,517,897,065.7022778988 seconds! is this a very high overhead query?

Comment: @BillStig The likely reason for the poor performance is the fact that I need to generate all possible pairs from your `items` table, which only lists individual values.  Can you generate a table containing all pairs?  If so, then the query should execute much more quickly.  You may also try Spencer's answer, if that would be any faster than mine.

Comment: actually I think this will work as there wont be so many pairs. could you tell me one additional thing? how would I specify that  both t1.BAND and t2.BAND would need to have the active field in their rows set to 1. I tried this but this is all a bit over my head  WHERE
im.primaryuid IS NULL OR im.disavowuid IS NULL and t1.active=1 and t2.active=1

Comment: actually I believe adding it on the items SELECT in the parenteses above worked.

Comment: I added a check on active in the subquery which generates the pairs, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: INNER JOIN items t2
        ON t1.BAND <> t2.BAND
        WHERE t1.active=1 and t2.active=1

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use an anti-join pattern

```
SELECT a.colname
     , b.colname
  FROM items a
  JOIN items b
    ON NOT ( a.colname <=> b.colname ) 
  LEFT
  JOIN item_matches m
    ON m.fA = a.colname
   AND m.fB = b.colname
  LEFT
  JOIN item_matches o
    ON o.fA = b.colname
   AND o.fB = a.colname
 WHERE m.fA IS NULL
   AND o.fA IS NULL
 ORDER BY NULL
 LIMIT 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6498ec/2

Comment: still testing this, only returning 1 item instead of the 2 but also incredibly high query time when order by changed to rand();

Comment: doing `ORDER BY RAND()` would require that MySQL generate the entire resultset (essentially a cross product of every `items` matched with every `items`, excluding those pairs that have a match), and then evaluating the `RAND()` function for every row in the set, and then doing a sort operation on the entire set. Once that is done, we can return a couple of rows. There's a reason I didn't do an `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Comment: For large sets, we need to ensure suitable indexes are available. The SQL Fiddle demonstration (link in this answer) includes definitions of suitable indexes.